# Mostrar item de um ArrayList em um JTextField

Tags: java, swing

**Boa noite comunidade, estou com um problema em um Projeto que estou trabalhando, criei uma table no mysql com algumas palavras, após isso fiz um ResultSet dessa table e guardei os nomes das palavaras obtidas desse ResultSet em um ArrayList, agora quero mostrar alguma Palavra que está nesse ArrayList na JTextField mas quando tento exibir, não mostra nada. aqui vai um Print do Problema e o Código Completo, desde já, Grato!.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxCrud.Collection;
import com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxSql.StmtExecute;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Menu extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private List Palavras;


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    
    List Palavras = new ArrayList<>();
    List PalavrasSql = new ArrayList<>();
    
    FactoryConnection fc = new FactoryConnection();
    Connection cc = fc.Connect();
    System.out.println("Conectado!");
    
    Statement stm = cc.createStatement();
    stm.execute("select * from Palavras");
    ResultSet rst = stm.getResultSet();
    while (rst.next()) {
        Palavras.add(rst.getString("Palavra"));
        System.out.println(Palavras);
    }
    
    System.out.println(Palavras.get(2));
    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Menu frame = new Menu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Menu() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JTextField PainelPalavra = new JTextField();
    PainelPalavra.setColumns(5);
    PainelPalavra.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    PainelPalavra.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    PainelPalavra.setFont(new Font("Sylfaen", Font.BOLD, 18));
    PainelPalavra.setEditable(false);
    PainelPalavra.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    PainelPalavra.setBounds(103, 67, 237, 114);
    contentPane.add(PainelPalavra);
    try {
        PainelPalavra.setText(Palavras.get(0).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Exception NullPointerException;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site. Seu código pode melhorar, entre outras coisas está misturando código de acesso a banco com código de apresentação, o acesso a banco está potencialmente sujeito a SQL injection e você está capturando exceções genéricas em vez de específicas (algumas nem deveria capturar). Eu particularmente sugiro levar para o Code Review StackExchange (nota: o pessoal lá fala inglês) quando estiver funcionando corretamente e aceitar o feedback que eles te derem lá. É um bom aprendizado.

Answer (score 1):

O erro é que você está declarando duas variáveis com o mesmo nome `Palavras` (que a propósito está fora do padrão do Java, o certo é em minúsculas) e fazendo confusão entre elas.

Uma é variável de instância (a que você não preenche) e outra é variável local do método `main()` (a que você preenche, só que não está usando no código do `JTextField`, está usando a outra).